# Does a conductor block the electric field across them?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

So I was learning electrostatics and came across this statement that the net electric field inside the bulk of a conductor (at equilibrium) is zero. This happens because the free charges inside the conductor rearrange themselves in order to cancel the external electric field.

My question is about what happens on the other side of the conductor (side opposite to the incoming external electric field). What will be the Electric field and potential there? Will it be due to the applied external field or the induced charges in the conductor? What will be its magnitude?

[image]

Comment: "Incoming"? That's not the appropriate idea for electrostatics. Is the field throughout all space before the conductor is placed ? Is the conductor finite?

Comment: Sorry for using the word "incoming", just thought it would be something creative.

Yes the field was throughout the space before placing the conductor and the conductor is of finite dimensions. Lets just say that the conductor is a solid cuboid.